# BigQuery How To Query Nested Fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I just started using BigQuery to explore my company's GA session data. I'm trying to generate a query that will allow me to generate the counts for each `experimentId` that has been passed to GA.

The `experimentId` is stored in `hits.experiment.experimentId` as a nested field. So far I have the following query, but it seems inefficient to have to do the left join to get this info. How can I optimize this query for variables that are nested in another nested array?

```
SELECT
  e.experimentId,
  count(*)
FROM
  `project-name.IDNUM.ga_sessions_20170527`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits.experiment) as e
GROUP BY e.experimentId
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `CROSS JOIN` operation again using the unnested `hits` field:

```
SELECT
  e.experimentId,
  count(*)
FROM
  `project-name.IDNUM.ga_sessions_20170527`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
  UNNEST(hits.experiment) as e
GROUP BY e.experimentId
```

You can also find some examples in [BQ docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#differences_in_repeated_field_handling) on how to process repeated fields (arrays) and a bunch of different techniques that will help you on several types of analyzes you want to run in BQ.